# Getting the last row of a table using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm dynamically creating table rows. So each time I add a row, I need to get the ID of the last `<tr>` so that I can create a new `<tr>` with `ID = "(the last row's ID) + 1"`. Is there any way to get the last row's ID using jQuery?

Answer (score 133, accepted):

```
$('#yourtableid tr:last').attr('id');
```

Comment: `:last` is deprecated as of jQuery 3.4.0

Comment: @evilReiko - any alternative available?

Comment: @ashleedawg you can use `.last()`, like this `$('#yourtableid tr').last().attr('id');`, check my answer below

Answer (score 17):

Old question, but here's a different way using JQuery traversal which is a bit quicker:

```
$("#TableId").find("tr").last();
```

An alternative method to ID your rows, if they are all sequential is just to get the number of rows + 1.

```
$("#TableId").find("tr").length + 1
```

Answer (score 15):

```
var id = $('table tr:last').attr('id');
```

Answer (score 9):

### 2019

As of jQuery 3.4.0 `:last` is deprecated, use `.last()` instead, like this:

```
var id = $('#mytable tr').last().attr('id');
```

Answer (score 2):

```
var tid=$('#tableid tr:last').attr('id');
alert(tid);
```

Answer (score 1):

There are two methods and they both work `$('#tableid tr:last')` and `$('#tableid tr').last()`

Answer (score 0):

Last row id of table

```
var lastid = $('table tr:last').attr('id');
var str = lastid .replace(/[^0-9]+/ig,"");
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use jQuery for that. You can handle it in CSS counters. The counters automatically increments the index values and it also handles the rearrangement of numbers in case a row is deleted from the midst. The CSS counters can be implemented as follows. Insert it into your CSS file that take care of the styles of the HTML table.

```
  #yourtableid tbody 
    {
      counter-reset: tablerow;
    }
  #yourtableid tbody .yourHTMLcellclass::before 
    {
  counter-increment: tablerow;
  content: counter(tablerow)". ";
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for a Vanilla javascript solution and this question is the first Google result, so here is the solution without Jquery :

```
    let table = document.getElementById('myTable') ;
    let lastLine = table.rows[table.rows.length-1];
```